# session_start() php variables

Tags: php, authentication, session, server, isset

I am trying to authenticate a user log in system from the PHP server side. I have been stuck on this for a few weeks now and can't seem to find my answer online anywhere. I hope that you guys can help me out.

Every time I call the php script the session variables seem to be lost. Here are the logs from my php server:

```
[Sun Nov  8 14:28:16 2020] 127.0.0.1:60706 [200]: /api/read.php
[Sun Nov  8 14:28:27 2020] Session Variables set!
[Sun Nov  8 14:28:27 2020] admin
[Sun Nov  8 14:28:27 2020] 127.0.0.1:60713 [200]: /api/read.php
[Sun Nov  8 14:54:34 2020] Session Variables set!
[Sun Nov  8 14:54:34 2020] admin
```

I am calling a php script from the same page multiple times by calling it from a typescript file:

```
readRecruitmentNeeds(): Observable<Policy[]>{
  return this.httpClient.get<Policy[]>(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/api/read.php`);
}
```

The php script has a session_start() with the variable name $_SESSION['uname']:

```
session_start();

$username="admin";
$pwd="admin";

if(isset($_SESSION['uname'])){
  readData();  //run if logged in
  error_log ("User is logged in",0);
  error_log ($_SESSION['uname'],0);
}
else{
  $_SESSION['uname']=$username;
  error_log ("Session Variables set!",0);
  error_log ($_SESSION['uname'],0);
  
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Phil I edited my post to make it more clear. I am sorry, I seem to have completed left out the question on the original post.

Comment: PHP sessions are maintained via cookies. You would need to configure your XHR calls to include the [`withCredentials` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials).

Comment: @Phil would something like this work:

readRecruitmentNeeds(): Observable<Policy[]>{
  return this.httpClient.get<Policy[]>(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/api/read.php`, {
    withCredentials: true
  });

Comment: That would entirely depend on whatever `httpClient` is. If it's Axios, it might work however you might also run into CORS issues. Try it and see

Comment: @Phil one other detail that may be important is that I am calling the script from an Angular website. The withCredentials didn't seem to change anything when I added that (though I am not receiving any errors or anything from that either).

Comment: You would also need `withCredentials` on your login calls. IMO, authenticating an API with session cookies is not the best way. Token based authentication works much better

Comment: @Phil how would you recommend changing this code so that it would work?

Comment: If session.cookie_httponly is On, the session cookie will not be included in the HTTP request. Just something to check, since you're requesting via JS.